# Where are the VM .cfg files on XenServer 6?

Tags: xenserver

Background: I am attempting to use PCI passthrough to utilise a PCI-E card in a VM. I have a freshly installed server (which supports VT-d, and has it enabled) with XenServer 6.0.2 on it, and have successfully hidden the card from dom0 (it's showing up on pci-list-assignable-devices, anyway).

I have a working VM, and am attempting to assign the PCI device to this VM (as shown [here](http://www.xen-support.com/?p=151)).

> Now all we need to do is to assign the PCI Device to the guest domU.
>   For example we edit vhost1.cfg and add the following line:
>   pci = ['02:00.0']
>   This will assign PCI device 02:00.0 to guest domain named vhost1, and will give an exclusive access to it.

I can't find where XenServer 6 is storing these files. It seems from documentation that they may be stored in databases in /var/xapi, but documentation warns against editing these manually, preferring the XL command which doesn't have anything that seems similar to the instructions above.

Have I missed the location of the files, or a command to edit the databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command for this was "xe vm-param-set"

```
xe vm-param-set other-config:pci=0/0000:01:00.0 uuid=...
```

This mounted the PCI-E card to the virtual machine specified with the uuid field.